# Error 201 con la api de thedogapi.com

Tags: api, fetch

Estoy haciendo un upload a la api, pero me responde con un error 201 "undefined", segun yo tengo todo en orden pero no estoy seguro, les muestro lo que me arroja la consola y el código de la función

El código se ejecutaal darle click a un botón con la propiedad "onClick"

```js
async function uploadImage(){
    const form = document.getElementById("uploadImageForm");
    const formData = new FormData(form);

    console.log(formData.get("file"));

    const response = await fetch(API_UPLOAD, {
        method: "POST",
        headers:{
            "X-API-KEY": API_KEY,
            //"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        body: formData 
    })
    const data = await response.json();


    if(response.status !== 200){
        spanError.innerText = `Hubo un error ${response.status} "${data.message}"`;
        spanError.style = `
            background-color: #B22222;
            padding: 8px 4px;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 8px;
        `;
        console.log({data});
    }else{
        console.log("Subido con exito!!");
        console.log({data});
        console.log(data.url);
        showFavouritesDogs();
    }
}
```

Error en el segundo log, el primero es para saber que información tiene la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que dice la api que pasa cuando devuelve un 201? porque no es un codigo de error...

Comment: @gbianchi disculpa no lei bien el comentario, pero no encuentro la seccion de errores de este tipo en la api

Comment: Eso es un error tuyo de interpretación. Tienes `if response != 200` y pues, es 201. Pero HTTP 201 es [Created](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201) y significa que se creó un recurso exitosamente. ENtonces, error no hay en la API, pasa que tienes que validar diferente. Como te dijeron en el otro comentario, HTTP 2xx no es error.

Comment: @Alfabravo si creo que eso era en la validación, ya no me sale el mensaje de erro de arriba gracias

Comment: Entonces ya lo solucionaste? no era un problema real?